# Can We configure Chronounit to schdule week from Saturday to friday

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Mostly All calendars utilities for weekly are configured on either Sunday/Sunday or Monday/Monday.

I want to configure it from Saturday to  Friday:

suppose I have cumulate data for November month on the weekly basis:

```
var sample = Seq(("C1", "01/11/2018", 20), ("C1", "02/11/2018", 5),
  ("C1", "03/11/2018", 2), ("C1", "04/11/2018", 3), ("C1", "05/11/2018", 5),
  ("C1", "08/11/2018", 5), ("C1", "10/11/2018", 10), ("C1", "12/11/2018", 10),
  ("C1", "14/11/2018", 16), ("C1", "15/11/2018", 6), ("C1", "18/11/2018", 22)).toDF("id", "order_date", "orders")


sample = sample.withColumn(
  "order_date",
  to_date(unix_timestamp($"order_date", "dd/MM/yyyy").cast("timestamp")))

val Row(start: java.sql.Date, end: java.sql.Date) = sample.
  select(min($"order_date"), max($"order_date")).
  first

val weeksDF = (0L to ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(
  start.toLocalDate, end.toLocalDate)).
  map(i => java.sql.Date.valueOf(start.toLocalDate.plusWeeks(i))).
  toDF("order_date")



Desired Output: 

02/11/2018  25
09/11/2018  15
16/11/2018  42
23/11/2018  22
```

early help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add sample of the code you are using now?

Comment: Updated sample code. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it in a simpler way, you only need to get next Friday and aggregate all dates to next Friday, so you can get next friday for every date like this:

```
val localDate = LocalDate.now() // your date here
val nextFriday = localDate.`with`(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY))
```

then you will add a new column with next Friday and group by it and sum the count